# "Conditional branch out of range" when trying to cross-compile C++ code for Ubuntu 18.04 and ARM Cortex-A9

Tags: arm, g++, cross-compiling

I've recently asked a similar question, but have since gathered new information - I hope someone can help now.

I am trying to cross-compile code from a GitHub project for my Ubuntu 18.04. distribution and the ARM Cortex-A9 processor on a Xilinx Zedboard. Unfortunately, when compiling the project, I run into the following error:

```
/tmp/ccJ10dX1.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccJ10dX1.s:192265: Error: conditional branch out of range
/tmp/ccJ10dX1.s:192270: Error: conditional branch out of range
Makefile:32: recipe for target 'library' failed
make: *** [library] Error 1
```

I am using the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-6` cross-compiler, but have also tried other versions to the same result; running `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-6 --version` gives

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 6.5.0 20181026
```

Compiling the project using `g++` (just for Ubuntu) works as expected.

I've been trying to create a minimal working example and, in the process, found that the file causing the error is a large header file (which is 1.1 MB large). This header file contains several array definitions, for instance

```
const ap_uint<8> a [128][126] = {{ ... }};
```

which I assume to be the problem.

Is there any way I can circumvent this compiler error?

Comment: You could try `-mlong-calls`, but I don't think it will help as it looks like you have code that is too big.  Ie, it is not the function distance, but the function size that is the issue.  If '/tmp/ccJ10dX1.S' exists, I suggest you post **THE PORTION** near the error.  Eg. lines 192260-192275 for instance.